# $(T^{-1})^i == (T^i)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I wonder if the hypothesis in the title is true. And if so, some ideas to prove it. I know $(A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T$

**EDIT**: Edited the title to match the generic answer. T does not have to be triangular.

Comment: I did originally, and edited the post when it didnt work for me. Do I have to use $$ as against only $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^k(T^{-1})^k = T\cdot T \cdot ... T \cdot T^{-1} \cdot T^{-1} \cdot  ...  T^{-1} = I$, thus $(T^{k})^{-1} = (T^{-1})^{k}$ if I understand the question correctly

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!